# what does "relation" mean in the Category of hypergraphs?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, hypergraphs

in the ncatlab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hypergraph they defined the category of hypergraphs:
SimpHGrph has objects consisting of a pair of sets (V,H) equipped with a relation R⊆V×H, and morphisms (R⊆V×H)→(R′⊆V′×H′) consisting of pairs of functions (f:V→v′,g:E→E′) which preserve the relation, i.e., such that for all v∈V,e∈H, if (v,e)∈R then (fv,ge)∈R′.

my question is what does it mean by relation here? what type of relation would be in this? would it be the pair; the vertex singletons set and the edge containing those vertexes? for example the pair ({{v1},{v2},{v3}}, {v1,v2,v3}).
Pardon me, if this is too stupid to ask.

Comment: Pretty sure they intended you to use the definition [linked in the article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation)

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relation $R \subset V\times H$ literally means a subset in $V\times H$. It describes which vertices and edges are connected. For instance, the edge $e\in H$ is connected to a vertex $v\in V$ if and only if $(v,e) \in R$.

It generalises ordinary unoriented graphs in the sense that an edge $e$ might connect more than two vertices, e.g. if $(v,e),(v',e),(v'',e) \in R$ for three different vertices $v,v',v'' \in V$.